# OpenCv Video Display PyQt5

Tags: python, user-interface, opencv, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm working with opencv3, python 3 and pyqt5. I want to make a simple GUI in which I want open up a new window to play a video along with some other widgets when a button is clicked on the main window. I've used `QPixmap` for displaying images in the past so I create a label and try to set the frames in the pixmap in a loop. The loop works fine but I am unable to get a display of the video/new window.
The loop I want to execute in the new window looks something like this:

```
    def setupUi():
       vid=cv2.VideoCapture('file')
       ret, frame=vid.read()
       while ret:
           Qimg=convert(frame)
           self.label.setpixmap(Qimg)
           self.label.update()
           ret,frame=vid.read()
```

`convert()` is a function I've  written myself that converts the cv frame to `QImage` type to be set into the pixmap. 
I'm only a beginner with pyQt so don't know what I am doing wrong. I've read about using signals, threads for the new window and `QtApplication.processEvents()` but don't know how these work and how they'll fit into my problem. 
It would be helpful if someone could set me in the right direction and also point out some resources to create good interfaces for my apps using OpenCV and python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that this isn't running is that your while loop is blocking Qt's event loop. Basically, you're stuck in the while loop and you never give control back to Qt to redraw the screen.

Your update() call isn't doing what you think it is; it's updating the data stored by the object, but this change does not show up until the program reenters the eventloop.

There are probably multiple ways of handling this, but I see two good options, the first being easier to implement:

1) Call QApplication.processEvents() in every iteration of your while loop. This forces Qt to update the GUI. This will be much more simple to implement than 2).

2) Move the function to a separate class and use QThread combined with moveToThread() to update the data, and communicate with the GUI thread using signals/slots. This will require restructuring your code a bit, but this might be good for your code overall. Right now the code that is generating the data is in your MainWindow class presumably, while the two should be kept separate according to [Qt's Model-View design pattern](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html). Not very important for a small one-off app, but will help keep your code base intelligible as your app grows in size.

Comment: It's currently working with QApplication.processEvents()  but seems very inefficient with a very low fps. I feel like using pixmaps is not the way to go. Could you suggest any other widgets I might look into?

Comment: Sure, this is what I do to display video:camera_scene_ = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    camera_pixmapitem_ = new QGraphicsPixmapItem();
    camera_scene_->addItem(camera_pixmapitem_);

    camera_view_ = new QGraphicsView(this);
    camera_view_->setScene(camera_scene_);

Comment: @user244791 (Ignore the above) This is in C++ notation, but you should be able to translate it to Python. I create `QGraphicsScene`, `QPixMapItem`, and `QGraphicsView` objects in my `MainWindow` class; in each iteration of the loop, call `QPixMap::fromImage(frame)`, then `QGraphicsScene::setPixMap(qpixmap)`, and finally `QGraphicsView.update()`. Not sure this will give you any speed ups, but it is worth a try. You maybe should consider adding a `sleep` statement to the loop as well, since right now there is nothing throttling the rate.